# Apache redirect on new url with get parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

There is an old link of the type: forum.com.ua/comment.php?discussionID=1
There is a new link of the type: forum.com.ua/forum/discussion/1/{title discussion}

You need to register a rule for 301 redirects. I tried the following methods, but they do not work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^DiscussionID=1$ RewriteRule ^/?comments\.php$ http://forum.com.ua/forum/discussion/1/video-i-klip [L,R=301]


Redirect 301 /comments.php?DiscussionID=1 http://forum.com.ua/forum/discussion/1/video-i-klip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I independently found the answer to my question, I spread the solution that helped me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^DiscussionID=1$
RewriteRule ^/?comments\.php$ http://forum.com.ua/forum/discussion/1/video-i-klip? [L,R=301]
```

[Link to the right decision](https://serverfault.com/questions/440270/htaccess-redirect-from-old-dirty-url-to-a-clean-new-url-with-parameters/440299)